# R: c_across() very slow - is there a faster but elegant approach?

Tags: r, dplyr

The underlying topic of the question is really about the point buy system in D&D 5E, but while working on it, I notice that `c_across()` slowed things down enormously.

The approach

```
die_value <- 8L:15L
point_value <- c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 9L)

determine_points <- function(n) {
    sapply(n, function(x) point_value[which(die_value == x)])
}

sum27 <- crossing(
    d1 = die_value,
    d2 = die_value,
    d3 = die_value,
    d4 = die_value,
    d5 = die_value,
    d6 = die_value
) %>%
    mutate(across(d1:d6, ~determine_points(.x), .names = "{col}_points")) %>% # see next blocks for options
```

As a first try for summing the `d[n]_points` columns row-wise to `total_points`, I tried to do the obvious `rowwise %>% sum(c_across)` route

```
rowwise %>% mutate(total_points = sum(c_across(d1_points:d6_points)))
```

However, while running this it took *forever*. The more explicit version was really fast in comparison.

```
mutate(total_points = d1_points + d2_points + d3_points + d4_points + d5_points + d6_points)
```

Balancing speed vs convenience is always a challenge, but here the difference is huge.

Is there a better way to sum up certain rows of a dataframe, while maintaining a little agnosticity about the number of columns that need to be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe we're splitting hairs here, but it's slightly faster with `data.table`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
die_value <- 8L:15L
point_value <- c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 9L)

determine_points <- function(n) {
  sapply(n, function(x) point_value[which(die_value == x)])
}

dat <- sum27 <- crossing(
  d1 = die_value,
  d2 = die_value,
  d3 = die_value,
  d4 = die_value,
  d5 = die_value,
  d6 = die_value
) %>%
  mutate(across(d1:d6, ~determine_points(.x), .names = "{col}_points"))
```

```r
f_dplyr <- function(){
z <- sum27%>%
  mutate(total_points = rowSums(pick(d1_points:d6_points),na.rm = TRUE))
}

setDT(dat)
ptcols <- colnames(sum27)[str_detect(colnames(sum27), "points$")]

f_dt <- function(){
  z <- dat[, total_points:=rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = ptcols]
}
```

```r
microbenchmark(f_dplyr(), f_dt(), times = 500)
#> Warning in microbenchmark(f_dplyr(), f_dt(), times = 500): less accurate
#> nanosecond times to avoid potential integer overflows
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#>  f_dplyr() 4.488803 4.707517 5.770832 4.944641 6.483268 34.66739   500  a 
#>     f_dt() 3.091359 3.213519 4.418006 3.349700 5.003578 32.35970   500   b
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 8):

We could use `rowSums` instead of `sum` with `across` instead of `rowwise` + `c_across`.  With `rowSums`, we can also remove the `NA` if present

```
library(dplyr)
...
%>%
mutate(total_points = rowSums(across(d1_points:d6_points), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or in the newer versions (`dplyr version >= 1.1.0`), use `pick` to select the columns as we are applying the function `rowSums` on the whole subset of columns rather than on each column itself.   According to `?pick`

> With pick(), you typically apply a function to the full data frame.

> With across(), you typically apply a function to each column.

```
%>%
  mutate(total_points = rowSums(pick(ends_with("_points")), na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

If there are no NAs, an option is also to `reduce` with `+`

```
library(purrr)
...
%>%
   mutate(total_points = reduce(across(1_points:d6_points), `+`))
```

#### Benchmarks

```
> dim(sum27)
[1] 262144     12
> system.time(sum27 %>%
+ mutate(total_points = rowSums(across(d1_points:d6_points),
   na.rm = TRUE)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.021   0.006   0.027 
# stopped the timing
> system.time(sum27 %>% rowwise %>% 
+ mutate(total_points = sum(c_across(d1_points:d6_points)))
+ )
#Timing stopped at: 122.3 0.892 124.6
> system.time(sum27 %>%
+ mutate(total_points = reduce(across(d1_points:d6_points), `+`)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.030   0.010   0.039
```

Comment: That works a lot better. The only improvement I would add to that is instead of using the explicit `d1_points:d6_points` using `ends_with("points")` to make it more robust to changes in the number of columns.

Comment: @RobHanssen or use `matches("^d\\d+_points")`  I was thinking that, but then if you have any other columns not to consider, i.e. `c1_points` etc...

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarking. Any idea why the `rowwise/c_across` version is > 5000x slower?

-- to answer my own question: from the source code it seems that c_across is executed in interpreted R, while `rowSums` is probably executed in compiled code.

Comment: @RobHanssen yes, there is a compiled code in `rowSums` - `else .Internal(rowSums(x, prod(dn), p, na.rm))`

Comment: excellent answer, @akrun. I wonder if you would prefer `pick` over `across`, since you have been suggesting updated dplyr 1.1.0 answers recently

Comment: @GuedesBF Thanks. yes, you can just replace the `across` with `pick`.  it should work.  I didn't see much difference in timing, so used `across`

Comment: @GuedesBF the difference I find in the docs is. `With pick(), you typically apply a function to the full data frame.` and `With across(), you typically apply a function to each column`.  Here, I think `pick` would be more suitable as we are kind of selecting the subset of data.

Comment: yes, I agree pick is the go-to here, as I always felt weird calling `across` without a `.fns` argument. I believe rowSums is the typical case for pick. It hardly makes any difference, though.

Comment: I'll take any reasonable answer. I'm most familiar with dplyr, but willing to learn others.